# creating lists depending on sign changes

Tags: python

I have excel Data (float) in one column where 20 changes of sings occur in every couple of hundred lines. The list is a couple of thousand lines long but simplyfied it looks like this `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -5, ...]`.

I need lists containing all numbers to the point where a sign change occurs and then start a new list until the next sign change. So in total I want as many  lists returned as there a sign changes. I need those to do numerical integration. I can do that though...

Can you give me an example with a short array like the one above? I don't really care if it gives the resluts as the return in a function or defines new variables. Whatever is easier or more elegant.

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to group by sign, you can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -5]


def groupby_sign(lst):
    return [list(group) for _, group in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x < 0)]

result = groupby_sign(data)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [-5]]
```

Comment: @AlexanderK Glad I could help. If my answer help you, please consider marking it as accepted

Comment: Slightly shorter (not necessarily better): `groupby(lst, key=0 .__lt__)`

Comment: well damn, Seems like my laptop cant compute 6000 excel lines. Is it more efficient to use a csv file with less decimals? Might it make sense to split it and try myself on multithreading? I have a i7 Quad Core (8th gen.)

Comment: nevermind, i'll just delete every second or third line in excel